# `python:safety` failing for `wheel` and `py`

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, python-wheel, python-py

I have a `python:safety` job in a gitlab cicd that uses `safety` version `2.3.2` to check for safety issues. The job looks like this in my `.gilab-ci.yml` file:

```
python:safety:
  extends: .python:project-image
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install safety==2.3.2
    - safety check
      --ignore 44715
```

After running `safety check`, the `python:safety` job fails because of `py` and `wheel` version with the following error:

```
+==============================================================================+
|                                                                              |
|                               /$$$$$$            /$$                         |
|                              /$$__  $$          | $$                         |
|           /$$$$$$$  /$$$$$$ | $$  \__//$$$$$$  /$$$$$$   /$$   /$$           |
|          /$$_____/ |____  $$| $$$$   /$$__  $$|_  $$_/  | $$  | $$           |
|         |  $$$$$$   /$$$$$$$| $$_/  | $$$$$$$$  | $$    | $$  | $$           |
|          \____  $$ /$$__  $$| $$    | $$_____/  | $$ /$$| $$  | $$           |
|          /$$$$$$$/|  $$$$$$$| $$    |  $$$$$$$  |  $$$$/|  $$$$$$$           |
|         |_______/  \_______/|__/     \_______/   \___/   \____  $$           |
|                                                          /$$  | $$           |
|                                                         |  $$$$$$/           |
|  by pyup.io                                              \______/            |
|                                                                              |
+==============================================================================+
| REPORT                                                                       |
| checked 159 packages, using free DB (updated once a month)                   |
+============================+===========+==========================+==========+
| package                    | installed | affected                 | ID       |
+============================+===========+==========================+==========+
| py                         | 1.11.0    | <=1.11.0                 | 51457    |
| wheel                      | 0.37.1    | <0.38.0                  | 51499    |
+==============================================================================+
```

I am installing the latest version of `py` in pipeline (`py==1.11.0`). Regarding the wheel, I have no idea from where it is being installed and dont know how I can update it or make sure latest version is being installed. Is there any way to fix this issue other that ignoring or `allowe_failure` on the pipeline job?

Comment: What exactly does "failing" mean? What exact error do you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GinoMempin thanks for your comment, I have added the error I am getting in the pipeline.

Comment: Where/How are you defining your project's package dependencies? In a requirements.txt file? Or are you using some virtual env manager like pipenv or poetry when running in the pipeline? Either way, pinning the version then installing specific versions of packages should have fixed it. Is your pipeline running in a container or a virtual env?